# phpMyadmin errors

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Im running on MAC 10.7.4 web server, installed the latest version of apache, php and mysql. Now I have phpadmin running but I get this message when I log in.

"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."

I have been googling for the past hour because I'd like to enable these features. I have been only coming up with vague answers on how to set this up. I'm more of a beginner so I need some help!

Comment: Did you "click here" to find out why?

Comment: Are you sure you *need* those features?

Answer (score 0):

To use some of the extended features of phpMyAdmin, it needs to have its own database where it can store settings.

Have you read this section of the docs? 
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#linked-tables

It talks about a `.SQL` file that you need to run on your server which sets up the necessary tables.  You can run this script in either phpMyAdmin or the MySQL command line tool.